# PHP Include Won't Show in Firefox

Tags: php, html, css

I have a PHP `include` placed into my page which is meant to call a .php extension with 2 images inside of a DIV.

Unfortunately it is showing up in Chrome and IE - but not Firefox. In Firefox it appears as nothing but 2 blue hyperlinks. I'm guessing the issue must be somewhere in my CSS(?) but I'll let you guys be the judge, because I'm out of ideas.

The main page :

```
<!-- ADVERTISING BANNER BEGINS -->
  <?php include('banner.php'); ?>
<!-- ADVERTISING BANNER ENDS -->
```

Which is calling :

```
<link href="css/railProductStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<!-- ADVERTISING BANNER BEGINS -->
<div id="advertisingbanner">
  <a href="http://rsiweb.org/trade_shows/rsicma2014/" alt="">
    <img src="images\shelf-banner-left.png" alt="RSI/CMA 2014" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://www.innotrans.de/en/" alt="">
    <img src="images\shelf-banner-right.png" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
<!-- ADVERTISING BANNER ENDS -->
```

Which is using the CSS :

```
/* ADVERTISING BANNER */
#advertisingbanner {
  width: 890px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 55px;
  margin-left: 55px;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Browsers have no idea what happens on the server.

Comment: If you have an issue just for Firefox, it means that the problem is not linked with PHP.

Comment: Are you on a Windows computer?

Comment: `link` should be place inside the `<head></head>`

Comment: Use `/` instead of `\ ` in image paths.

Comment: Sorry, completely new to PHP. I am on a Windows computer.

Which link?

Comment: @user3628937 - This -> `<link href="css/railProductStyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: are you sure your images are in correct folder??

Answer (score 1):

Put the style calling on header and leave the rest of the code on your php file. 
Also, I recommend you to use class instead id on that div. 
Also 2: switch the slash on your image url path such as "images/shelf-banner-left.png"

Comment: Can I ask why a class would be better than an ID? Not questioning the statement, just genuinely curious as class vs ID has always been something I've never thoroughly looked in to.

Comment: Classes are good when it will be used in multiple places, ID's should be used for unique elements.

Comment: You're using a div for ads, maybe you'll need to use the same div for more ads. Once you use ID, some problems may occur. Class are better for situations like this and works better for several situations. For example, you can create a class .ad and another class .topad. and use both classes on same div such as <div class= ad topad"></div>. on .ad class, you define background color for example, and topad class you can define size and position.

Comment: Nice! Thank you. Would that perhaps explain why the positioning of this DIV is being ignored?

Comment: You may positioning this element in a wrong way. try to use position:relative with 55px left. If nothing happens, create a JSFiddle file then I can help you tough

Comment: Is that a practice that should be used as a rule? (position)? 

It seems to be fixed now that I've cleared my cache, however I'm curious as to whether I should practice defining the position as a habit?

Comment: The position relative or margin fields is not a rule. depends on each case. if you have a div, and this div is a 300x300px, you need to keep it floated on right, with a space on left you can use margin-left or padding-left. But, margin-left will give you a true space, while padding-left will "expand" the size of your div. you can try it in many cases :)

Answer (score 1):

use img src as

```
<img src="images/shelf-banner-right.png" alt="" />
```

instead of

```
<img src="images\shelf-banner-right.png" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the filename:

```
images\shelf-banner-left.png
```

`\` is not valid, however some browsers support this, you should always use `/` instead.
As far as I know, only firefox has problems with it though.

Just to make clear, Windows uses these kind of slashes in their filesystem (`\`) While Unix based OS's use `/` instead, web URL's should always be a forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to disable your adblock plugin and see if it solves your problem.
I had similar experience once.